# Extract 3-level content from paginated pages with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I have a seed url (say `DOMAIN/manufacturers.php`) with no pagination that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="st-text">
        <table cellspacing="6" width="600">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer1-type-59.php"></a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer1-type-59.php">Name 1</a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer2-type-5.php"></a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer2-type-5.php">Name 2</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer3-type-88.php"></a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer3-type-88.php">Name 3</a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer4-type-76.php"></a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer4-type-76.php">Name 4</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer5-type-28.php"></a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer5-type-28.php">Name 5</a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer6-type-48.php"></a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="manufacturer6-type-48.php">Name 6</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

From there I would like to get all `a['href'] 's`, for example: `manufacturer1-type-59.php`. Note that these links do NOT contain the `DOMAIN` prefix already so my guess is that I have to add it somehow, or maybe not?

Optionally, I would like to keep the links both in `memory` (for the very next phase) and also save them to `disk` for future reference.

The content of each of these links, such as `manufacturer1-type-59.php`, looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="makers">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="manufacturer1_model1_type1.php"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="manufacturer1_model1_type2.php"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="manufacturer1_model2_type3.php"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-band">
        <div class="nav-items">
            <div class="nav-pages">
                <span>Pages:</span><strong>1</strong>
                <a href="manufacturer1-type-STRING-59-INT-p2.php">2</a>
                <a href="manufacturer1-type-STRING-59-INT-p3.php">3</a>
                <a href="manufacturer1-type-STRING-59-INT-p2.php" title="Next page">»</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Next, I would like to get all `a['href'] 's`, for example `manufacturer_model1_type1.php`. Again, note that these links do NOT contain the domain prefix. One additional difficulty here is that these pages support pagination. So, I would like to go into all these pages too. As expected, `manufacturer-type-59.php` redirects to `manufacturer-type-STRING-59-INT-p2.php`.

Optionally, I would also like to keep the links both in `memory` (for the very next phase) and also save them to `disk` for future reference.

The third and final step should be to retrieve the content of all pages of type `manufacturer_model1_type1.php`, extract the title, and save result in a file in the following form: (url, title, ).

**EDIT**

This is what I have done so far but doesn't seem to work...

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ArchiveItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()

class ArchiveSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'gsmarena'
    allowed_domains = ['gsmarena.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.gsmarena.com/makers.php3']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['\S+-phones-\d+\.php'])),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['\S+-phones-f-\d+-0-\S+\.php'])),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['\S+_\S+_\S+-\d+\.php']), 'parse_archive'),
    ]

    def parse_archive(self, response):
        torrent = ArchiveItem()
        torrent['url'] = response.url
        return torrent
```

Comment: Is it a public site and you can share the URL? (would help to help)

Comment: Sure, the above example is based on the following seed url (http://www.gsmarena.com/makers.php3). However, the most important thing for me is to understand the underling idea. Still, if you could send me an working example it would be much easier for me to understand all these concepts. :)

Comment: hi @alecxe I just added what I have tried so far (although it doesn't work - yet!). could you please have a look? thanks!

Comment: @alecxe hi! my solution above looks like ok but I would like to use proxies as well. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for coming back lately. Have you solved your current issue?

Comment: @alecxe Hi, thanks a lot for your response. My solution seems ok but I get banned from the website after crawling about 300 urls. So, it would be nice to know how `scrapy` utilizes `proxies` with a handful example. I would really appreciated it! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you better use BaseSpider instead of CrawlSpider

this code might help

```
class GsmArenaSpider(Spider):
    name = 'gsmarena'
    start_urls = ['http://www.gsmarena.com/makers.php3', ]
    allowed_domains = ['gsmarena.com']
    BASE_URL = 'http://www.gsmarena.com/'

def parse(self, response):
    markers = response.xpath('//div[@id="mid-col"]/div/table/tr/td/a/@href').extract()
    if markers:
        for marker in markers:
            yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + marker, callback=self.parse_marker)

def parse_marker(self, response):
    url = response.url
    # extracting phone urls
    phones = response.xpath('//div[@class="makers"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()
    if phones:
        for phone in phones:
            # change callback function name as parse_events for first crawl
            yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + phone, callback=self.parse_phone)
    else:
        return

    # pagination
    next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@title, "Next page")]/@href').extract()
    if next_page:
        yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + next_page[0], callback=self.parse_marker)

def parse_phone(self, response):
    # extract whatever stuffs you want and yield items here
    pass
```

**EDIT**

if you want to keep the track of from where these phone url's are coming, you could pass the url as *meta* from **parse** **to parse_phone** through **parse_marker**
then the request will look like

```
 yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + marker, callback=self.parse_marker, meta={'url_level1': response.url})

yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + phone, callback=self.parse_phone, meta={'url_level2': response.url, url_level1: response.meta['url_level1']})
```

Comment: hi! any particular reason why you are in favor of `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider`? Btw, my solution above looks like ok but I would like to use proxies as well. any ideas?

Comment: difference between crawl and base spider refere [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)

you can use proxy middleware [proxy-middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792152/setting-scrapy-proxy-middleware-to-rotate-on-each-request)

Comment: thanks for the link in regards to `proxies`; i find it difficult though to understand how is works - yet! Ideally, what I would like to do is give a list of ip:port, for example, [ip1:port1, ip2:port2, ip3:port3] and and let `CrawlSpider` chose one at a time (randomly). note that I still want to use `CrawlSpider`. so, how can I do that?