# How to get around being blocked with "Scrapy"

Tags: scrapy

**Background:**

I am planning on buying a car, and want to monitor the prices. 
I'd like to use `Scrapy` to do this for me. However the site, blocks my code from doing this.

**MWE/Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy    # adding scrapy to our file

urls = ['https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/volkswagen/golf/7-series/wagon-bodystyle/diesel-fueltype/']

class HeadphoneSpider(scrapy.Spider):   # our class inherits from scrapy.Spider
    name = "headphones"
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/volkswagen/golf/7-series/wagon-bodystyle/diesel-fueltype/']# list to enter our urls
        # urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=headphones&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aheadphones&ajr=2']

        for url in urls:            
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)  # we will explain the callback soon


    def parse(self, response):
        img_urls = response.css('img::attr(src)').extract()
        with open('urls.txt', 'w') as f:
            for u in img_urls:
                f.write(u + "\n")


    def main():
        scraper()
```

**Output:**

```
   ...some stuff above it
   2020-01-10 00:37:59 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/volkswagen/golf/7-series/wagon-bodystyle/diesel-fueltype/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
   ..some more stuff underneath
```

**Question:**

I just don't know how I can circumnavigate this `not allowed` to parse the prices, Km's etc. It would make my life so much easier. How can I get past this block? FWIW I also tried it with BeautifulSoup which didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping in Python - Preventing IP ban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133200/scraping-in-python-preventing-ip-ban)

Comment: @ggorlen I should use Scrapy? It seems like another level after BeautifulSoup - help!~?

Comment: I don't know, but there are many dupes of this question and articles around the web on this exact problem, so I think you'll need to show a bit more research before this question is likely to receive useful attention as there are a wide variety of general techniques (described in the dupe and other threads) that may help you.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm trying to use Scrapy, but I'm getting the `not allowed` card... :/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to avoid being blocked by the sites while **scraping** that:

- Set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`
- Increase `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` between your requests like 3 to 4 seconds depending upon the site behavior
- Set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` to 1
- Use proxies or pool of proxies by customizing `proxy_middleware` and serve the cause
- Carry site cookies in requests so the site does not identify bot behavior

You can try these solutions sequentially

Comment: where would i write these commands? Arre you able to provide a snippet of code please? I am new to `scrapy`

Comment: You have to write these in the settings file. Please refer to Scrapy settings docs, it will give you a clear idea on how to use these settings [https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html]