# How to avoid being banned while scraping data from a login based site?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to create a script using which I can parse few fields from a website without getting blocked. The site I wish to get data from requires credentials to access it's content. If it were not for login thing, I could have bypassed the rate limit using rotation of proxies.

As I'm scraping content from a login based site, I'm trying to figure out any way to avoid being banned by that site while scraping data from there. `To be specific, my script currently can fetch content from that site flawlessly but my ip address gets banned along the way if I keep on scraping`.

I've written so far (***consider the following site address to be a placeholder***):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    req = s.get(url)

    payload = {
        "fkey": BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml").select_one("[name='fkey']")["value"],
        "email": "some email",
        "password": "some password",
    }
    
    res = s.post(url,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for post_title in soup.select(".summary > h3 > a.question-hyperlink"):
        print(post_title.text)
```

> How can I avoid being banned while scraping data from a login based site?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"?  Do you mean that the site doesn't recognize your login credentials, or do you mean that the site thinks you're a robot and deliberately refuses your requests?

Comment: Check out the edit @John Gordon. I've edited the post to answer what you asked. However, the script can scrape data from that site but gets banned along the way. The site does not throw any captcha but bans ips. As I need to log in to that site before scraping data from there, I wish to know what possible way I can follow to avoid getting banned. Thanks.

Comment: Two parts here. **Ethical**: if the site is banning you, then they're against you scraping them. Maybe not completely, maybe they have a policy? You could check robots.txt, they could have some policy you could follow. **Technical**: the site might not want to handle extra load, so you could add delays between your actions. This might be in line with their policy too, so possibly the best/easiest solution. Alternatively, you could run your script from something like AWS lambda, spawning multiple instances with different IPs, but this isn't ethical.

Comment: Adding delay may help get me few more data but ultimately leads to the banning. How come spawning multiple instances with different IPs help as I need to log in to access the content? Don't you think they can track my ip using my credentials no matter how many ips come into play?

Comment: As for delay, maybe increasing it would help. They might just have a rate-limit set-up per-IP. If you manage to fit within the limit, you're not banned :)
The rate-limit could be set-up with or without account in mind. Creating multiple accounts from same IP and using them one after another could help or it could get you banned within the same time span.
Spawning multiple instances using one account might help or it could still get you banned. It depends on the implementation, and the only way to know is to test.

Answer (score 9):

Going direct to the point of "any efficient way to **avoid** being banned" there is **no way**.

I would compare this situation with a shark attack. It was the shark's decision, not yours.

However, there are some techniques that you can use to mitigate the "shark attack"... But first, let's make it clear that you are "attacking" the shark first, swimming in its domain.

The technique would be: "Creating a human scraping script".

The word `human` here is referred to make random mistakes sometimes. Some of them listed below:

- Insert some random delays between your tasks;
- Click on some wrong link, wait few seconds, go back;
- Log you out from the system, wait a minute or two, log you in again;
- If you have a list of links on a page to click and then grab the data for each page, **don't do** it in order;
- If you have a page that shows the results in pages, get the results **don't do** it in order (ex. 1, 5, 2, 9, 10, 3, 7, 4, 8, 6)
- Don't rush, get few data each day

However, the most effective way would be to contact the website owner and offer a partnership or pay for accessing the data using an API or something like that if they have this service.

Comment: Also worth mentioning Javascript, and lack thereof when using requests. While your request may be valid, the site is likely performing some form of fingerprinting. From the site's perspective, you've logged in but haven't executed their script, so you must be a bot. If possible, try using selenium. Although that may require some additional work to "blend in" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver

Comment: Sure thing. There are many cases where Selenium will do the job much better than requests.

Answer (score 3):

I add a similar issue writing a library using selenium to fetch financial data from websites.

The only efficient way I found was to add a random delay around 1 second to mimic a human behavior, with the following command after each request (at the end of my loop)

```
time.sleep( 1.0 +  numpy.random.uniform(0,1) )
```

You will have around 60 requests by minutes. You can adjust the 1.0 to have a frequency which is ok for the website.

If the website computes the frequency of your requests, it will finds exactly one minute, which is higly suspicious, but right now I didn't find one which did this.

Comment: Your answer actually works for a short period of time. I may try adding a big cool down time after every 50 texts sent.

Answer (score 1):

**While trying to scrape websites that do not want to be scraped is not recommended, it is possible.** You would need to setup proxies for your code to run through. I have used ScrapingHub to host my my scraping projects. It will change its ip address through proxies automatically.

Comment: I know I can bypass the rate limit using proxies within the script. However, the main thing that you forgot to address is what to do when the site requires login. Don't you think the site will still identify your script as a bot using your credentials even when you implement proxies within the script?

Comment: Have you tried setting the user agent in your code?

Comment: Yep, I used this library `fake_useragent` to produce random user-agent.

Comment: Btw, it's not that I used proxies in a login based site and failed. I just wish to know what might be the consequence when I implement proxies within the script to parse content from a site requires login. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Paulo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66463877/3694381)'s answer that discusses many techniques to act `human` you can workaround the IP blocking issue by frequently (or after some requests) changing the IP address from which you are sending the request.

**Proxy Method:**

It can be done programmatically. This [website](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-rotate-proxies-and-ip-addresses-using-python-3/) shares some points to take care when doing so. A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447709/python-requests-change-ip-address) is asked at SO.

**Existing Tools**

There are some existing tools/framework that might help. [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/), [Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133200/scraping-in-python-preventing-ip-ban). The [tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/beginner-to-advance-web-scraping-guide-in-python-ba24dca5dce0) here provides amazing techniques that you can use as well. You can rotate  `user-agent`, `proxy`, and `referer` to differentiate your request every time.

To prevent the credentials from being banned, either rotate your credentials or contact them directly. If they are asking credentials then it is the idea that they don't want to load that part of their website. Act `human` would be the preferable way in that case.

Answer (score 0):

one more useful thing to do is to switch to selenium.
Selenium spawns a web browser instance every time you run your **scraper** so the site will think you are a legit person.

Answer (score 0):

Use the selenium web driver to open a browser and load the page you want, and then you can do the **scrape** on the browser you have running. This is a way that the site does not block you since it contains headers etc. that simulates the interaction of a user with the site

for example, using chrome web

`self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path +/driver//chromedriver.exe',  chrome_options=self.options) self.driver.get('site to scrape')`

this will open a browser, then **scrape** over this browser
check this [selenium-python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: FYI ‘to scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish. The correct term for what you’re doing is __scrape__

Comment: It also depends on the website, usually some websites ban IP access and thus selenium cannot used to scrap data.